# Mustache and Jquery Plugin Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, templates, mustache

I am using mustache js with a accordion plugin. My idea is to use an external template file, along with an external json file and pull the templated file into an accordion widget (using a plugin). It all works fine except my accordion is not working. It only works when an alert is used to check the code. Html is basic Jquery library call and a div to hold content. Any help much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

    $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html', function () {
        var scripts = ['js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', 'js/mustache.js']; //add as many script as required here
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
                $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
                    var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                });
                //alert('done'); 
                //not working without alert?
                $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the function `$.getJSON` gets executed asynchronously, therefore the instruction `$('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion();` gets executed before this one: `$('.jsoncontent').html(info);` When you put the `alert` it provably works because you are stoping the execution and in that case the instruction `$('.jsoncontent').html(info);` has time to finish before `$('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion();` gets executed.

A possible fix, maybe not the best one, but the most strait forward could be to make the execution of the $.getJSON to run synchronously, to do that replace this block of code:

```
                $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
                    var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                });
```

for this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
                    var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                },
    data: {},
    async: false
});
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that there is another important issue with your code, apparently in the execution of your "for" you are loading the Jquery library first and then you are loading Mustache library after. But you are trying to use the function "Mustache" after you have loaded the JQuery library and BEFORE you have loaded the "Mustache" library... That's a problem.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

    $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html', function () {
        var scripts = ['js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', 'js/mustache.js']; //add as many script as required here
        var scriptsLoaded =0;
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
                scriptsLoaded++;
                if(scriptsLoaded==scripts.length){
                    $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
                        var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                        var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                        $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                        $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion();
                    });
                }    
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Pasted code and not getting a response in the .jsoncontent div now.

Comment: My bad, try now. At the end of the success function there was a ");" that should have been "},", I already fixed.

Comment: still got a problem with this no response when I use ajax call. Would a function be a better solution?

Comment: If this code: "$.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) { " is getting a response, then the code that I suggested will get a response too. $.getJSON is just a shorthand of the "$.ajax" function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Okay I now have a repsonse - however still same result no accordion functionuality. Thanks for your thoughts, any other suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer, in the execution of your "for" you are loading the Jquery library first and then you are loading Mustache library after. But you are trying to use the function "Mustache" after you have loaded the JQuery library and BEFORE you have loaded the "Mustache" library... That's a problem.

Comment: no response with no code I have re-worked an extra get script in the get json callback. Appreciate all your efforts!

Comment: No problem, please, just out of curiosity, try the code of the last edit that I made, I'm pretty sure that that code will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Josep is right, if it works when you're using an alert() it's because thats blocking execution, which gives time for the ajax call to work - and the callback to execute.

However, rather than refactoring your code that much - you could just move the call to `$.liteAccordion()` in to the call back. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

    $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html', function () {
        var scripts = ['js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', 'js/mustache.js']; //add as many script as required here
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
                $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
                    var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                    var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                    $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                    $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion(); //move here
                }); //eof .getJSON
            }); //eof .getScript()
        } //eof for()
    }); //eof load()
}); //eof ready()
```

However, I'm a little curious as to your choice of using `$.getScript()` - as the code in your `for()` loop doesn't actually need to run like that; there's no point getting the JSON once for every script; it would be preferable to get every script and THEN get the JSON once.. For example..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

    $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html', function () {
        var scripts = ['js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', 'js/mustache.js']; //add as many script as required here
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
                //just get the script; this callback doesn't need to do anything really
            }); //eof .getScript()
        } //eof for()

       /* we're out of the for() loop now, so this will only make the call
          once; however - all our scripts are loaded so it will work */
       $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
            var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
            var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
            $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion(); //move here
        }); //eof .getJSON

    }); //eof load()
}); //eof ready()
```

This solution once again places the `$.liteAcordion()` call in a callback, so it will be executed after Mustache.js has been called.

It's worth remembering AJAX is asynch at times, as it can cause headaches if you don't make the most of callback functions etc.

**However, as @Josep points out in the comments below you still run the risk of `$.getScript()` not having finished executing yet; this will be an issue for the more scripts you include in your array.**

With that in mind it may be good to have a slight refactor and call `$.getJSON()` from your `for()` loop; but ensure that it is definitely the *last* iteration. (*edit: I see Jesop actually had an identical solution - I know most of us are on here to get points, but if you're going to accept an answer - accept his, he got there first ;)* )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

    $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html', function () {
        var scripts = ['js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', 'js/mustache.js']; //add as many script as required here
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
                if( i == (scripts.length -1) )
                  $.getJSON('json/data.json', function (data) {
                      var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                      var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                      $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                      $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion(); //move here
                  }); //eof .getJSON

            }); //eof .getScript()
        } //eof for()
    }); //eof load()
}); //eof ready()
```

Comment: The problem with the second block of code that you have proposed is that most likely when the function "$.getJSON" gets executed the JQuery library won't be loaded yet... So I think that he will have to make a better use of the callback function of $.getScript if he wants to make this work.

Comment: Well spotted Josep. Lemme edit my post to take that in to consideration actually!

Comment: I just fixed it in my answer

Comment: Yeah, great minds think a like. I was going to go with an ```if()``` block. I would +1 your answer again but I can't. ;)

Comment: I would +1 your answer again too, but I can't ;)

Comment: @Josep - well I've essentially told the OP to accept your answer instead of mine, as I see we've essentially gone for an identical fix - but there's no denying you got there first. Well played :P

Comment: Thanks a lot Fergus, it's always nice to collaborate with people who care more about finding the right answer than to get more points.

Comment: I think that we both made a very basic error: we can't use the "i" variable to check if that is the last script loaded, because by the time the 2ond script is loaded the main "for" will have already finished and therefore the value of "i" will be "scripts.length" (that's why we are using a callback function XD). Therefore we need to update a "count" variable every time that the callback function is called. I have already fixed it in my answer. I hope that I have explained myself properly.

Comment: Just got back, LOL - that makes perfect sense; it's so obvious too! Good work! :) I agree though, it's good to collaborate with someone looking for an answer and not a point.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop causes issues as pointed out by josep - I have kept the scripts array for now as it will be useful to load js that moustache does not affect. A get script in the JSON callback works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('head').append("<script id='templateHolder' type='text/template'></script");

        $('#templateHolder').load('templates/template.html',function(){
            var scripts = ['js/mustache.js'];
            //problem here for any scripts directly affected by moustache templating.
                 for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
                             $.getScript(scripts[i], function() {  
                                $.getJSON('json/data.json', function(data) {
                                            var template = $('#templateHolder').html();
                                            var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
                                            $('.jsoncontent').html(info);
                                            $.getScript('js/liteaccordion.jquery.js', function() {
                                            $('.jsoncontent').liteAccordion();
                                     });
                                 });
                            });
                 }
        });
    });
```